# Passing props through a "template" component

Tags: react-typescript

I'm building a template component using React with TypeScript but i'm facing an issue i'm unable to solve. I'm posting this in case anyone knows how to approach it.

1. My project has a `MyComp` component that invokes `TemplateComp` using a subcomponent `GraphComp` and the data that Graph requires.
2. `TemplateComp` invokes and stylises the `Graph` subcomponent plus adds some props that are needed (such as `customPropertyA`) next to `graphData`.
3. `GraphComp` is requiring certain parameters that graphData needs to render properly.

The issue i'm facing is related to the types definition from GraphComp to MyComp while passing through TemplateComp. It may seem that (because TemplateComp defines graphData as any, as it is unknown to it) MyComp understands that graphData can also be any, but in reality it should be equal to the properties that Graph is requiring as Props (but not all of them).

**Is there any way to let MyComp and TemplateComp infer the types that GraphComp is asking for?**

Here is my code:

```js
import { Component, ElementType } from 'react'

export default class MyComp extends Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TemplateComp
          Graph={GraphComp}
          graphData={{
            value: 0
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class TemplateComp extends Component<
  {
    Graph: ElementType
    graphData: any
  },
  {}
> {
  customPropertyA = 'hello'

  render() {
    const { graphData, Graph } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Graph {...graphData} customPropertyA={this.customPropertyA} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class GraphComp extends Component<
  {
    value: number
    customPropertyA: string
  },
  {}
> {
  render() {
    return <div>my value: {this.props.value}</div>
  }
}
```

I'm perfectly fine with modifying how these components work. However, i still need the 3 layer approach and to be able to define GraphComp's props from within MyComp and TemplateComp separately.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to approach this, i managed to fix it by calling the mounted JSX instead of mounting it in TemplateComp and removed properties from it as they can also be described in MyComp.

```js
import { Component, ElementType } from 'react'

export default class MyComp extends Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TemplateComp
          Graph={<GraphComp value={0} customPropertyA={"hello"} />}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class TemplateComp extends Component<
  {
    Graph: JSX.Element
  },
  {}
> {
  render() {
    const { Graph } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {Graph}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class GraphComp extends Component<
  {
    value: number
    customPropertyA: string
  },
  {}
> {
  render() {
    return <div>my value: {this.props.value}</div>
  }
}
```